# Generic Continuous Delivery Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a Jenkins pipeline template and placed the script (written in groovy) in inline Editor.  It builds the application and deploys to an environment when job is triggered.

XML documents housed in GitHub turn various pipeline features on and off. For example if an environment is "controlled" then an approved change order is required before deploying to the environment. Each application can have multiple configurations. Every application uses the same pipeline script.

Now script is complex and huge with 3000 lines of codes. I would like to break it into small routines, modularlize, and scalable. Can anyone suggest me some ideas to refactor the script

Comment: Have you considered [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)? And if you find that it does not fit your need, please explain why, as doing so might clarify what you are after.

Comment: Thank you Hugues for the reply. I am using only one Generic pipeline template for all the pipeline jobs. My thought was loading of Jenkinsfile(housed in GitHub) from pipeline template. Then load the routines/steps related to (build and deploy) stages from global pipeline libraries( housed in GitHub).  Can all the applications use the same Jenkinsfile(making it global) not application specific? can Jenkinsfile and shared libraries can be housed in same repository?

Comment: I would not recommend to put the Jenkinsfile and the shared library with the same repository. Most of the time you want the Jenkinsfile to be versioned with the application code. Whereas the Shared library should be versioned separately.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my solution to create a pipeline template here: Jenkins pipeline template

The idea is to create a [Shared Library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) with a global variable that provides a pipeline template. It can be then be used within a Jenkinsfile by simply calling a method from the Shared Lib.